# Zero Bytes Sent When Sending Axlsx Gem Generated File From Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, axlsx

Attempting to prompt a download window and stream an XLSX file using Ruby Sinatra and the AXLSX gem, my excel file serializes successfully to local file, so I know its a valid excel doc, but I need it to transfer content to the end user. There haven't been any docs online with examples of AXLS and Sinatra used together, only rails. Help is appreciated!

```
class Downloads < Sinatra::Base
  get '/downloads/report' do
    ## ...
    Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
      p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'tab name') do |sheet|
        ## ...
      end
      content_type 'application/xlsx'
      attachment 'cost-code-dashboard.xlsx'
      p.to_stream # unsuccessful
      # p.to_stream.read # unsuccessful as well
    end
  end
end
```

I have also tried the following snippet unsuccessfully

```
Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  ## ...
  send_file p.to_stream.read, type: "application/xlsx", filename: "cost-code-dashboard.xlsx"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue had everything to do with how `Axlsx::Package.new` was called, the helper functions were not available inside Axlsx, the following solution worked - online documentation said that the below content_type was better

```
get '/downloads' do
  content_type :'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

  p = Axlsx::Package.new
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Test') do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ['Hello world']
  end
  p.to_stream
end
```